# Elasticsearch is not starting for Search Guard error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, search-guard

I'm trying to configure Search Guard admin. here is my elasticsearch.yml configurations:

```
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: /home/rsa-key-20200528/search-guard-ssl-master/example-pki-scripts/node-0.crt.pem
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: /home/rsa-key-20200528/search-guard-ssl-master/example-pki-scripts/node-0.key.pem
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_password: changeit
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: /home/rsa-key-20200528/search-guard-ssl-master/example-pki-scripts/ca/root-ca.pem
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false

searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
  - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=Test,C=DE
```

After this configurations, I'm unable to start my elasticsearch. Here is the full error from my "/var/log/elasticsearch/my-application.log" file.

```
[2020-07-05T04:51:39,896][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] version[7.8.0], pid[2328], build[default/deb/757314695644ea9a1dc2fecd26d1a43856725e65/2020-06-14T19:35:50.234439Z], OS[Linux/4.9.0-12-amd64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/14.0.1/14.0.1+7]
[2020-07-05T04:51:39,907][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]
[2020-07-05T04:51:39,908][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-3499631201687762622, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=deb, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
[2020-07-05T04:51:44,548][INFO ][c.f.s.s.SignalsPainlessExtension] [node-1] Loaded script whitelist: org.elasticsearch.painless.spi.Whitelist@3a5e2525
[2020-07-05T04:51:44,571][INFO ][c.f.s.SearchGuardPlugin  ] [node-1] ES Config path is /etc/elasticsearch
[2020-07-05T04:51:44,877][INFO ][c.f.s.s.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore] [node-1] JVM supports TLSv1.3
[2020-07-05T04:51:44,884][INFO ][c.f.s.s.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore] [node-1] Config directory is /etc/elasticsearch/, from there the key- and truststore files are resolved relatively
[2020-07-05T04:51:44,889][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [node-1] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.floragunn.searchguard.SearchGuardPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:616) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:558) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:164) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) [elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) [elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) [elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) [elasticsearch-cli-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) [elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:607) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/rsa-key-20200528/search-guard-ssl-master/example-pki-scripts/node-0.crt.pem" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1036) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:747) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.checkRead(UnixPath.java:818) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory(Files.java:2314) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.checkPath(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:827) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.resolve(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.initSSLConfig(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:343) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.<init>(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:164) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.SearchGuardSSLPlugin.<init>(SearchGuardSSLPlugin.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.SearchGuardPlugin.<init>(SearchGuardPlugin.java:227) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:607) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 15 more
[2020-07-05T04:51:44,908][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node-1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.floragunn.searchguard.SearchGuardPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.floragunn.searchguard.SearchGuardPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:616) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:558) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:164) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:607) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:558) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:164) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/rsa-key-20200528/search-guard-ssl-master/example-pki-scripts/node-0.crt.pem" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1036) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:747) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.checkRead(UnixPath.java:818) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory(Files.java:2314) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.checkPath(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:827) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.resolve(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.initSSLConfig(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:343) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.<init>(DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore.java:164) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.SearchGuardSSLPlugin.<init>(SearchGuardSSLPlugin.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at com.floragunn.searchguard.SearchGuardPlugin.<init>(SearchGuardPlugin.java:227) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:607) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:558) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:164) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.0.jar:7.8.0]
    ... 6 more
```

I'm following [this](https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/search-guard-installation) and [this](https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/sgadmin#configuring-the-admin-certificate) documentation.

**what is wrong here? why elasticsearch is not starting?**

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error message it seems the location of your certificates is:

```
/home/rsa-key-20200528/search-guard-ssl-master/example-pki-scripts/node-0.crt.pem
```

However, the docs state that all certificates

> must be under the config/ directory, specified using a relative path
> (mandatory)

(https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/configuring-tls#using-x509-pem-certificates-and-pkcs-8-keys)

Please try moving the certificates and key(s) in the config directory.

Comment: I moved those file but now I'm getting another erro:

```Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: Error while initializing transport SSL layer from PEM: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: /etc/elasticsearch/node-0.key.pem```

Comment: If you don't mind, would you like to take my server credentials and check what is the problem?